# How do I pass multiple variables from ajax to php?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'm trying to pass two variables into this AJAX function, how would I go about doing that?

```
function showInfo(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET","query1test.php?"+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

And what I want tot pass into the AJAX requestion is lname, and year? Is there a way to go about that?

```
<input type="text" name="lname" Onchange="showUser(this.value)"> <br>
<select name="year" >
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
    <option value="2010">2010</option>
    <option value="2009">2009</option>
</select> <br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

Thanks for your help, I'm still a beginner.

Answer (score 5):

I would have used [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) for this. It is much easier if you are using different browsers. The Ajax part (get request) is done with one line and you can use selectors to find the needed values.

In this bit of code, I set the onchange event for input named "lname". When the onchange event is triggered I get the value from the name field and the year from the select element. Then I send a get request to `query1test.php`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name="lname"]').change(function() {
        var name = $('input[name="lname"]').val();
        var year = $('select[name="year"]').val();
        $.get('query1test.php?name='+name+'&year='+year);
    });
});
```

In the PHP script (`query1test.php`) you can retrive the values from $_GET. For example:

```
<?php

$name = $_GET['name'];
$year = $_GET['year'];

echo $name . ' - ' . $year;
```

You might want to do something with the data returned from the PHP script. An example of that is:

```
$.get('query1test.php?name='+name+'&year='+year, function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll be tinkering around with it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're passing as str, but by the looks of things it is expected to be your query string - the very answer to your question. So in my response, I will replace str with what it would be without any validation:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","query1test.php?lname="+document.getElementById("lname").value+"&year="+document.getElementById("year").value,true);
```

And in addition I would give an id of lname to your text input and an id of year to your select.

```
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" Onchange="showUser(this.value)"> <br>
<select id="year" name="year" >
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
    <option value="2010">2010</option>
    <option value="2009">2009</option>
</select> <br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

That would pass your request as $_GET vars.

Any reason why you would not want to use jQuery for this?

Comment: Thanks Kai_Qing. No specific reason for not using jQuery, not too familiar with it.